Subsetting global data based on latitude and longitude resulting in "TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index"
I have a atmospheric global data set of size 721, 1440 from a grib2 file. Y and X are lat and lon values. Gridded to 721, 1440 to match the data.
extent=[10.0, 350.0, -60.0, 60.0]
lat_bnds,lon_bnds=[extent[2],extent[3]],[extent[0],extent[1]]
condition =((y[:,:] > lat_bnds[0]) & (y[:,:] < lat_bnds[1])) & (x[:,:] > lon_bnds[0]) & (x[:,:] < lon_bnds[1])
print ('subsetted variable',variable2[condition]) 


Traceback (most recent call last):

(subroutine stuff deleted)
 
File "plottingroutine.py", line 114, in FXmapWXM
    print ('subsetted variable',variable2[condition])
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

I've seen this given as a simple example of how to subset data. I can't figure out what I am doing wrong.
I expected to get a subset of the met data within the extent=[10.0, 350.0, -60.0, 60.0]
to  perform statistics on and eventually plot.
I went through my code and made sure all of the grib files I input were converted to numpy arrays. I assumed that all 2d input would automatically be read in as arrays since I thought lists were only 1-D.

You don't show what variable2 is in your code, but most likely it is a a list and not a numpy array.
This question is similar to: TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index with 1D numpy indices array. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

OMG. It's a a list. I am going to try to fix all the inputs into arrays and start again. Standard PEBCAC error.  Thank you!
